# Actualizacion Masiva Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

tengo que realizar una actualización masiva en codeigniter donde tengo un campo denominado "**supervisor**" el mismo esta por defecto tiene "**null**" la idea es actualizar todos los registros con el valor de 1.

He intentado algo así:

```
$data = array(
    'supervisor' => 1
);
$condicion = " !=1 ";
$this->db->where("supervisor", $condicion);
$this->db->update("parte", $data);
return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

No me lanza ningún error pero tampoco actualiza los registros gracias por cualquier sugerencia.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si se trata de solo hacer un update con un valor en específico como lo tienes, lo puedes realizar con una consulta nativa así:

```
$sql = "UPDATE parte SET supervisor = 1 WHERE(supervisor != 1);";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if ( ! $query ) {
  return var_dump($this->db->error());
}
return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Si necesitas agregarle a tu condición que quieres actualizar a 1 todos aquellos que sea diferentes de 1 y además nulos, puedes hacer esto:

```
$sql = "UPDATE parte SET supervisor = 1 WHERE(supervisor != 1 OR supervisor IS NULL);";
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
if ( ! $query ) {
  return var_dump($this->db->error());
}
return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Y si lo necesitas así como lo tienes, puedes hacer esto:

```
$data = array("supervisor", 1);
$this->db->where("supervisor !=", 1);
$query = $this->db->update("parte", $data);
if ( ! $query ) {
  return var_dump($this->db->error());
}
return $this->db->affected_rows();
```

Del último ejemplo que te mostré, puedes entender un poco mejor sobre cómo manejar estos operadores [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5226261/codeigniter-active-record-not-equal).

Saludos y permíteme saber si tienes algún problema o duda sobre mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias me fue de mucha ayuda..!!